# Is sail.js active?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm contemplating to do a POC on NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. I've recently learnt about sails.js. It sounds good but before spending some time on it, I should know that whether it's community is active and it's road map.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no well defined problem nor is there a well defined method to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if SO is the place for such questions. Nobody really knows how long an open source framework or library will last: it depends on the author, community and a lot of other factors.

Some good indicators are:

- activity and number of contributers on github. For Sails: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails check it there.
- Issue resolvement time
- Stars and forks.

If issues are resolved quickly, multiple people are working on it on at least a monthly basis and there are a considerable amount of stars and forks, you can probably rely on it for a while.

To answer your question: Based on those factors I've described, I think you are fine using sails.

- There are **100+ contributors**,
- the latest commit was **only days ago**,
- there are **2500+ closed issues**: seems there there is some dedication in that project.
- And the community likes it as wel: **12000+ stars** is a lot.

The roadmap is also specified for this project: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/ROADMAP.md#roadmap

Comment: Thanks Justus Romijn